# Reflexive object and infinite products

Tags: ct.category-theory, lambda-calculus

The category CPO of cpos and continuous functions has a reflexive object, i.e. an object $A$ such that $A\times A\simeq A$ and $A\simeq A^A$. Since CPO has countable products, my question is whether or not there is also an $X$ such that $X\simeq X^X$ and
$$X\simeq \Pi_{n\in \mathbb{N}}X$$
where the RHS is the product of $X$ with itself countably many times.

Comment: Cpo=complete partial order, I guess?

Comment: @DavidRoberts According to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_partial_order, the meaning of unadorned "cpo" is ambiguous...

Comment: @Mike hmm, good thing I asked. "The category CPO of cpos" is such a stereotypical category theorist thing to say!

Comment: You are right, I should have written the definitions. So for cpo i mean a directed complete partially ordered set (probably dcpo is a better abbreviation), i.e. a poset in which every directed subset has a supremum. An arrow is a monotone function that preserves suprema of directed sets.